# how to monitor database transaction?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, transactions

I have written a webapplication for payroll system which can do (insert,update,delete) to mysql database.

I want to know

how many transaction happened in mysql database ?
how many transaction happened in mysql database during start_time and end_time ?

Comment: aren't there any MySQL log files ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL has command counters. They can be seen with `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE "COM\_%"`. Each execution of a command increments the counter associated with it. Transaction related counters are `Com_begin`, `Com_commit` and `Com_rollback`. Also `Uptime` is the number of seconds since server start. Reading and graphing these values or their delta yields the information you ask for.

There are also counters for `Com_insert`, `Com_update`, `Com_delete` and variations thereof. You might want to graph these as well.

Comment: thanks @Isotopp your solution is simple and exactly what i was looking for. [mysql - documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-status.html) show status like 'com_select';

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this the answer you are looking for you I've heard that the following JDBC logger is very useful for tracking what an application is doing to a database.  It should show where your application is opening and commiting transactions.  You should then be able to write some scripts to process the logs to determine the number transactions.

> http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/

It basically sits between your application and the *real* database driver.  You add a log4jdbc prefix to your JDBC URL.  For example, if your normal jdbc url is

```
jdbc:mysql://db.foo.com/webapplicationdb
```

then you would change it to:

```
jdbc:log4jdbc:mysql://db.foo.com/webapplicationdb
```